# A função Strata do R não foi encontrada (Ubuntu)

Tags: r

Boa tarde,
Estou estudando R no Ubuntu (16.04 LTS).
Ao tentar utilizar a função strata através do comando abaixo:

```
amostra = strata(infert, c("education"), size = c(5, 48, 47), method = "srswor")
```

Ocorre o erro abaixo:

Error in strata(infert, c("education"), size = c(5, 48, 47), method = "srswor") : 
  não foi possível encontrar a função "strata"

Versão do R no Ubuntu R version 3.4.2 (2017-09-28) -- "Short Summer"

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 6):

Algumas funções que utilizamos no R não vem associada ao `base package`.
Portanto devemos instalar o package que desenvolveu a função que queremos usando `install.packages("nome do package")` e depois chamar o package usando `library(nome do package)`.

Caso você não saiba o nome do package, você pode usar a função `findFn()` do package `sos`.

```
install.packages("sos") # se ainda não instalou o package
library(sos)

findFn("strata", maxPages = 1)
```

**EDITADO**:

De acordo com Rui Barradas, o package é provavelmente `sampling`.

Comment: Eu fiz o mesmo, com o pacote `sos`, mas acho que tendo em conta os argumentos da função da pergunta deve vir do pacote `sampling`.

Comment: Legal, editei a sugestão do pacote. Obrigado

Comment: Então devia incluir isso na resposta, assim só removeu a sugestão anterior.